# typescript declare type in filter loop?

Tags: typescript

I got error of

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 1: { abc: number; }; 2: boolean; 3: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ 1: { abc: number; }; 2: boolean; 3: string; }'
```

with below code

```
interface testInterface {
  1: { abc: number };
  2: boolean;
  3: string;
}

const test: testInterface = {
      "1": {abc:123},
      "2": false,
      "3": "123"
    } 

Object.keys(test)
.filter((key) => !test[key] )
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-forest-12llz?file=/src/App.tsx:55-131

where should I defined the type? I've defined the `test` with an interface, it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: "*I've defined the `test` with an interface*" where? And what's the interface?

Comment: Also: what do you expect to happen here? What type do you expect `test[key]` to have?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not your fault that you face this problem, it's sort of a design flaw of TypeScript, the reason is stated in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208).

The reason why you face this problem is that `Object.keys(x)` don't return the `keyof typeof x` , instead it returns a `string[]`.

That is why you got the error `type 'string' can't be used to index type 'testInterface'`, because the `keyof testInterface` is `(1|2|3)[]` which obviously cannot be matched with `string[]`.

Therefore, one way to solve this problem is to used type casting with the `as` operator.
You can try this out at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAkgZzASXNeTkDeAsAFDLICMAXIcnAEYI0gCuAtvdMgL4Dcp5AEw16Ae1EAbCHBD8yyAMw0MUUAHM53UqQSiQGVBAw10WHLEQoAvIQHlkAIgoOaBOoxoVBCngBo75A6CLsjwEmgQ-vKBCiFO3g6kfNokABQA8vQAVhAIYAB0ANYQAJ5oqaYAlHRoyCwghSCiAO4gNcipxSWiMIYY2JAWSJUA2gC6laT5MMASg6mdpdVWAHzIAISmI10TyEA).

```
interface testInterface {
  1: { abc: number };
  2: boolean;
  3: string;
}

const test: testInterface = {
    "1": { abc: 123 },
    "2": false,
    "3": "123"
};

(Object.keys(test) as unknown as (keyof testInterface)[])
.filter((key) => !test[key])
```

Note that casting to `unknown` is necessary, if not you will get another error saying `string[]` cannot be casted to `(1|2|3)[]`.

This is a pretty ugly solution to be frank, but might be the only viable solution at the time of writing until TypeScript's devs decide to refine the return type of `Object.keys`.

Comment: omg I don't even know what does the snytax trying to say.. what if I want to omit testInterface and use `any` instead.?